# Query & Order posts by custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, php, custom-field

I'm trying to query a custom post type "jogos" where the meta value "data_de_lancamento" (launch date) is <= than today's.
That field uses the format dd/mm/yy.

The returned posts from that query must then be ordered Descending by the custom field "views".

My current code is:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
$data = date("d/m/y");
global $wpdb;

$sql = "SELECT wposts.*
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta2
WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
AND wposts.ID = wpostmeta2.post_id
AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'views'
AND wpostmeta2.meta_key = 'data_de_lancamento'
AND wpostmeta2.meta_value < $data
AND wposts.post_type = 'jogos'
AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY wpostmeta.meta_value ASC";

$resultado = $wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `meta_query` parameter of the WP_Class when running a query. Something like this should point you in the right direction.

```
$data = date("Y-m-d");
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'jogos',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'data_de_lancamento',
            'value' => $data,
            'compare' => '<='
        )
    ),
    'meta_key' => 'views',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC'
 );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The catch with this is that it's nearly impossible to compare dates in the form of 'dd/mm/yy'. As such, this code will not do the trick. You need to first change your date format to 'yyyy-mm-dd'. This is a much more useful way of performing the date comparison. Also, you may need to do some testing with the operator to make sure it's functioning right.

Note that I specify using `meta_query` which is new to WP 3.1. `meta_key` and `meta_value` are deprecated as of WP 3.1; however, to order by `meta_value` you actually still have to specify `meta_key` as the value you want it to order by. Confusing and not well documented.

References:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any way i can change the date format for the query, and then put it back as it was? So the date displayed is the format i want?

Comment: Update: I just tried your code, edited manually the date formated on the admin panel, but still, the query returns nothing.. :/

Comment: To answer the first question, I would recommend storing the date in the database as yyyy-mm-dd as this is easiest for sorting tasks. Then, when you read out the data, run it through the php `date` function in order to format it however you want, e.g., `date('m/d/y', strtotime($date));` As for your second comment, without knowing more about the situation I cannot help. I would recommend trying to change the operator, or further playing with the query until you get something to work. I'm happy to keep helping, but I need more to work with.

Comment: I've tried storing the date with the format yyyy-mm-dd, still no results in the query.. The `date` function is also using that format. No results so far... What else would you need to help me with this?

Comment: Any help is still appreciated :)

Comment: Can you pastebin your code? I'll have a gander.

Comment: Which part? Sorry for the confusion... PS: I can give you access to the Admin panel/template if you wish so, but to do that please add me in MSN or so, so we can talk realtime :)